# @Resource - Difference between attributes name and lookup?

Tags: jakarta-ee

`javax.annotation.Resource`

What is the difference between attributes "`name`" and "`lookup`"? When do you use `name`and when do you use `lookup`? By reading the javadoc I can't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as it says name is product specific and is not supported by many application servers. So for now you should use lookup as it should be portable and cross platform. You specify global JNDI of the given resource.

Comment: It's not clear at all in the javadoc. name: The JNDI name of the resource. lookup: The name of the resource that the reference points to. It can link to any compatible resource using the global JNDI names.